# Is querying by a PRIMARY KEY in MySQL faster than other queries?

Tags: mysql, performance, benchmark, query-performance

I have two queries that return on a dataset of 200,000 records with apparently the same performance. The first looks up a primary key, and the second a varchar(32) with no special constraints.

Am I using MySQL BENCHMARK correctly here?

`` SELECT BENCHMARK(2000000000, (SELECT `col` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = somekey LIMIT 1)) ``

`` SELECT BENCHMARK(2000000000, (SELECT `col` FROM `table` WHERE `string` = somestring LIMIT 1)) ``

They both have a similar run time. I understand the fastest possible query should be the case where it's the primary key without any other predicates, but I thought the second form (a random 32 digit hex number with no constraints) would run significantly slower. Am I missing something? Maybe my dataset is too small to see the difference?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%';`

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%'; query_cache_limit = 1048576, query_cache_min_res_unit = 4096, query_cache_size = 1048576, query_cache_strip_comments = OFF, query_cache_type = OFF, query_cache_wlock_invalidate = OFF`